# QJsonDocument::toJson() generates extra large text. Is there way to fix it?

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5, qjson

I have made class that convert `QList<qreal>` (very big list) to JSON string, but it generates a extra large text.

Here is code:

```
QJsonObject rootObject;
rootObject.insert("Test",0.05);
qDebug()<<QJsonDocument(rootObject).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
```

And I have tried equal code:

```
QJsonObject rootObject;
rootObject.insert("Test",QString("0.05").toDouble());
qDebug()<<QJsonDocument(rootObject).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
```

And debug ouptut is always:

```json
{"Test":0.050000000000000003}
```

I want to get short output like this:

```json
{"Test":0.05}
```

Is there way to fix `QJsonDocument`? Or make some decimals count rounding/limit?

Comment: Why are you converting a double to a string and then back to a double?

Comment: @Merlin069 because all my input data has come from double value that converted from QString. And it is a proof that bug is not in that toDouble conversion.

Comment: I see, since you missed the quotes around 0.05 passed into QString, I didn't realise that the input was originally a string. I've tested QVariant and that works, so you're right that the json conversion is the problem. It's not ideal, but you could write a string, instead of the double.

Comment: Thanks for trying it. Yes I'll use strings if there is no solution for double.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @Merlin069 Mac OS X Yosemite, and tested on Open Suse Linux, the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X I tried the following: -

```
QVariant d(0.5);
QJsonValue val = QJsonValue::fromVariant(d);

qDebug() << val.toDouble();
```

This prints out 0.5, as expected.

However, I think the problem is due to [floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples). QJSonDocument is representing the number as accurately as possible, but does not have a function to limit the number of decimal places represented, as is present in [QString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#setNum-9).

Though not ideal, if your really want 0.5 represented this way, you can write a string value instead of the double.

Comment: Single value looks ok, but I need to get valid json string with names and values.
So I used QJsonArray and QJsonDocument to convert all to string. Looks like it QJsonDocument problem only.

Comment: I just need to convert QJsonObject to valid JSON string. QJsonObject contains this doubles and output is to large. Some doubles converted correcty, but I have tested 0.5 and it always huge.

Comment: I think the problem is floating point precision and have updated the answer accordingly.